# RECORD to JSONB, no automatic way?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

`jsonb_build_object('a',a, 'b',b)` is redundant (not "automatic"), and `to_jsonb(row(a,b))` is ugly because ignores column names... Is there no way to do the right thing?

---

### NOTES

A typical query is something as

```sql
SELECT a,b, record_to_jsonb(c,d,e) as info FROM t
```

I need a *dynamic solution*, but, to illustrate, a *statical solution* is to define a datatype,

```sql
CREATE TYPE mytest AS (c text, d int, e boolean);
SELECT a,b, to_jsonb(row(c,d,e)::mytest) as info FROM t; -- work fine!
```

---

PS: why PostgreSQL not offers **the inverse of [`jsonb_to_record()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)**? 
Either I'm not realizing to the see an elegant and eficient way to use `to_jsonb` (most probable), or, maybe PostgreSQL's architect-developers forgot the concept of [library function orthogonality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_instruction_set)... There is no technical problem to implement a nice `record_to_jsonb()` function, as demonstrated before by functions like [`xmlattributes(a,b)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html), that captures colunm name and value.

Comment: The inverse is just `to_jsonb` called with a record. (The problem is rather that the `row()` constructor doesn't let you choose column names - `to_jsonb` works fine with whole table rows). Can you show the full query you're working with?

Comment: Hi @Bergi I edited with a typical query... Can you illustrate a query, perhaps some LATERAL JOIN, to use your suggestion?

Comment: Please comment the negative votes

Comment: For a dynamic solution where you'd want to choose the attribute names (just like with `xmlattributes`) you'd indeed use `jsonb_build_object`. I don't see anything wrong with that. Really the problem is not missing `to_jsonb` functionality, but that postgres doesn't have an easy way to build arbitrary records with nice column names.

Comment: instead of `to_jsonb(row(a,b))` why not just use `select to_jsonb(r) from (select a,b from ..) r`

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, see final answer, now with `lateral (select c, d, e) subq`... Or you are suggesting other syntax for subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select a, b, to_jsonb(subq) as info
  from t
       cross join lateral (values (c, d, e)) as subq(c, d, e);
```

or shorter, abbreviating CROSS JOIN syntax and using SELECT clause directly

```sql
select a, b, to_jsonb(subq) as info
  from t, lateral (select c, d, e) subq;
```

Could something like this be more in line with your use case?  My thought would be to keep `a` and `b` in the json and let the requesting code just ignore it.

```sql
select a, b, to_jsonb(t) - 'a' - 'b' as info
  from t
```

Comment: Hi Mike, the query works fine (!) and perhaps is optimized by SQL compiler, but it is not a solution for the PostgreSQL's problem, it is not a "simple way"  for a programmer express a query, and have the same redundance tham `jsonb_build_object('c',c, 'd',d, 'e',e)`... So,  programmers will prefer jsonb_build_object, don't you think?

Comment: PS: testing with `explain analyse` have the **same performance** (interesting!) tham `to_jsonb( row(c,d,e)::dtype )` and `jsonb_build_object('c',c, 'd',d, 'e',e)`.

Comment: @PeterKrauss  I see your point and added another possibility to my answer.

Comment: The syntax of the new solution is elegant for column complement (!), but the performance cost is hight (JSONb is slow in redo its structure)... For non-complement and performance, *jsonb_build_object* is better.  I added at your original solution an alternative syntax with SELECT clause, that **seems the most elegant and best performance**:  the accpted solution of the question.